# my app on iPhone 6,6s,6p and 6sp is stretched after upgrade to iOS9

Tags: ios, ios9

The app works fine on ios9 simulator and on any real devices with ios8. But on iphone 6 and 6p, when ios upgrade to ios9, the app is stretched and the layout is same as iphone5.

I have also checked the LaunchImage in images.xcassets. There are four launch images:Retina HD5.5, Retina HD4.7(iphone portrait ios8,9), 2x and Retina 4(iphone portrait ios7-9).

I don't know why the app is stretched. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide `LaunchScreen.xib` file for your Xcode instead of launch images. This way you will eliminate your problem for sure. After creation of this `xib` file, navigate to your project file and to Target -> Info -> App Icons and Launch Images -> Launch Screen File -> select your created `LaunchScreen.xib` file. Done. Profit.
Inside that viewController in xib file you can put `UIImageView` with the same images you used as launchImage.

Btw, starting from iOS9 you can substitute your `LaunchScreen.xib` with storyboard file, but this will work only in new Xcode, as far as I know.

Comment: Should't we use Storyboards instead of xibs these days? Just curious.

Comment: Depends. I sometimes create xibs when I need only `UIView` object. No point of creating the whole storyboard file for it. And keeping everything in one single storyboard is a bad idea as well in case you don't work on the project alone - just wait till you get those conflicts...

Comment: Good point. I don't use them both, except for the LaunchScreen. Everything is done only with code. :)

Comment: well, not using AutoLayout makes things run faster, that's for sure, in case you don't use it. But other than that - it just saves time. But, in case you know how to use it wisely :)

Comment: My point is that you have no control of how your objects are constructed behind the scenes, thats why I prefer to build everything from inside my code. ;) Anyways, I'm not the person who asked the question here, I just was curios about XIBs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90689/discussion-between-soberman-and-devandartist).