# iOS 9 's build on device is different from simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, layout, ios-simulator, ios9

After upgrading my test device from iOS 8.4 to iOS9 . I realize everything inside the app appears larger and out of proportion. What is shown in the simulator is different when i build it on the device.

I do not have this problem in all my previous version. Does anyone have a similar problem as me? I'm trying to find out if its my xcode configuration problem or is it due to a bug on the iOS 9 since it is only recently released.

Below is the screenshot of what is seen in the "simulator" and what is seen in the "actual device".

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer for this. There is a similar post on this previous to that which I couldn't find earlier.

[my app on iPhone 6,6s,6p and 6sp is stretched after upgrade to iOS9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32796924/my-app-on-iphone-6-6s-6p-and-6sp-is-stretched-after-upgrade-to-ios9)

The answer to this is to use a launch image storyboard/nib instead of using launchimage . This will fix the problem.